# Как сделать так что бы скрипт запускался автоматически для любого документа Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

Я написал свой скрипт для Google Doc документов.
Сейчас скрипт запускается только для одного единственного контейнера. 
Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии любого Doc файла скрипт запускался  автоматически для всех Google документов?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скрипт запускался при открытии любого Документа, его необходимо опубликовать как дополнение https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview